# Disable ol4 some default event listeners

Tags: openlayers, gwt-openlayers

Is there any chance to disable some default event listeners on some ol4 components or stop trigerring some basic events? For example, i want to push an element in ol.Collection without trigering the 'add' event, or change the geometry of a ol.Feature without trigering the 'change' event.

Comment: Is possible to create a sample Jsfiddle or anywhere.. where we can reproduce the same error or see whatever you have tried so far ?

Comment: See the comments from ending js part.
 http://jsfiddle.net/silviu_negoita/x2cg1L5u/

Answer (score 0):

ol.source.Vector.addFeatures() will add the passed features and then trigger a single CHANGE event - note that it does fire an ADDFEATURE event for each feature.